# Return values of functions in ActiveX controls

Tags: c++, com, activex, return-value

Why can functions in the main COM object of an ActiveX control return values of any `VARIANT` type, while functions in other ATL objects in a control must return an `HRESULT` error code and give their "real" return values via an additional pointer parameter, labeled `[out, retval]` in the IDL? Why this difference?

Comment: There is no difference. You perhaps need to post code snippets for better explanation.

Comment: @RomanR. I can have a function `CURRENCY getFileSize(BSTR filename)` in my ActiveX object and have a dispatch map such as `DISP_FUNCTION_ID(MyControl, "getFileSize", 
                            401, getFileSize, VT_CY, VTS_BSTR)`. But in other "ATL simple objects" in the same ActiveX control, I am forced to use the `STDMETHOD` function declaration and cannot use a dispatch map.

Comment: ATL produces true COM method functions. `DISP_FUNCTION_ID` creates an internal MFC map entry and MFC exposes real methods (late binding only, perhaps) which convert external calls to internal (simple style) functions.